# Ggplot in R how to show percentages

Tags: r

Having a dataframe containing the attributes: Fjob what is the father´s job and G3 which is the mark. I would love to be able to get see for each job group the % of the records which have approved the subject (given G3 > 9 is approved).

I have used the following code:

```
ggplot(dMat, aes(G3 > 9)) + geom_bar() +
  facet_wrap(~Fjob) +
  ggtitle ("Father job and approved info") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(vjust = +1.5, size = 12)) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
```

However, this does provide me the percentage related to all the records and does not group by the fathers job (shown bellow):
[Output Image:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XwNYT.png)

Please find attached also the header: [header Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7323.png)

Any light of how could I do this

Comment: can you share head(dMat)

Comment: @user2510479 edited the comment and added the header :)

Comment: Please share your data using `dput` or in a similar manner. Pictures are not searchable or copy/pasteable.

Answer (score 0):

What I did was to first create a subset where G3 > 9 and then use x = G3. I am not very clear on what you are trying to achieve. I used a play dataset to check code as your head(dMat) was a picture and I could not cut and paste it to check with your data.

```
dMatSubset<-subset(dMat, G3>9)

ggplot(dMatSubset, aes(x=G3)) + geom_bar() +
facet_wrap(~Fjob) +
ggtitle ("Father job and approved info") +
theme(plot.title = element_text(vjust = +1.5, size = 12)) +
scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
```